# Google cloud API dashboard doesnt show access, Despite YCBS benchmarks running

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to Google Cloud.

Running some YCSB benchmarks against it , Which are using a service account with full access to data store.

Also running from Compute with a service account on the instance with full access to all API's

The Datastore API was simply returning "UNAVAILABLE" (wrappered by YCSB), Which according to Google doc is a catch all error. It started working today suddenly.

No datastore API actions are being shown in the dashboard https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard, I can see compute actions and some previously executed gcloud CLI tool commands.

```
Google Cloud Datastore API  —   —   —   —   —
```

YCSB is using The betav3 API included when enabling the main API. The dashboard page has an [enable api] button which when you click just takes you to the library page, Logically you search for dashboard.

```
No results for dashboard
```

As you can see below Datastore is definitely being accessed.

```
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 121037.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 8.261936432661088
[TOTAL_GCS_Copy], Count, 11.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_Copy], Time(ms), 58.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_%_Copy], Time(%), 0.047919231309434304
[TOTAL_GCS_MarkSweepCompact], Count, 0.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_MarkSweepCompact], Time(ms), 0.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_%_MarkSweepCompact], Time(%), 0.0
[TOTAL_GCs], Count, 11.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME], Time(ms), 58.0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_%], Time(%), 0.047919231309434304
[READ], Operations, 497.0
[READ], AverageLatency(us), 102567.05030181087
[READ], MinLatency(us), 54944.0
[READ], MaxLatency(us), 304383.0
[READ], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 195839.0
[READ], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 274175.0
[READ], Return=OK, 497
[CLEANUP], Operations, 1.0
[CLEANUP], AverageLatency(us), 3.0
[CLEANUP], MinLatency(us), 3.0
[CLEANUP], MaxLatency(us), 3.0
[CLEANUP], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 3.0
[CLEANUP], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 3.0
[UPDATE], Operations, 503.0
[UPDATE], AverageLatency(us), 137206.58449304174
[UPDATE], MinLatency(us), 76160.0
[UPDATE], MaxLatency(us), 2041855.0
[UPDATE], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 223871.0
[UPDATE], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 303103.0
[UPDATE], Return=OK, 503
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your issue that the API actions did not show up in the dashboard right away? Are you still having issues using the current v1 API? I'm also not sure what you mean by "Logically you search for dashboard: No results for dashboard".

Comment: I mean the API actions never showed up in Dashboard even days after this post.

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue with the v1 API? Is this still an open question or was the issue only temporary?

Answer (score 1):

This might well be only a temporary GUI-related issue, a one-time event. For benchmark testing, there are some recommended tools, as described on the [Measure and compare performance page](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/measure-compare-performance).